# Open pdf embedded in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I have a webpage that show me some pdf uploaded previously, but I want that when I click on their link, open it into a named div.

My code:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <a href='pdf1.pdf'>pdf1</a>
    <br/>
    <a href='pdf2.pdf'>pdf2</a>
  </div>
  <div class='col' id='preview'>OPEN PDF PREVIEW</div>
</div>
```

If I click on "pdf1" or "pdf2" my two files may open into div with id PREVIEW

I've tried with some jquery functions, without luck.

Comment: are u using jquery? for `id='preview'` ? plz share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

you just have to pass your pdf path to url

Comment: with your solution it works, but i need some little things to make it better.

Comment: 1) with height and width fixed, my page is stretched because of iframe. there is a way to make iframe "invisible" and expand in his dimentions when i click on it's link?

2) i want to use jquery "toggle" to make it disappear when i click second time. it is possible?

Comment: ok Great, if it works for you, then you can upvote this and can also accept this as answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a link in an iframe, try to use target="iframeName", as seen at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target).

Comment: Combining with Insomania's answer, try the following:
a href="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" target="preview" where you have an iframe with the name of "preview"